# Incorrect test result for unit test of TimeZoneInfo member

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, timezone

Info:
using .NET 4.0 and VS 2012

Hi,

I'm about to unit test my own class which has got a member of type TimeZoneInfo. However, when I try to consider this member in my test, it always fails.

The following is a simplified example which verifies that _timeZone has correctly been initialized during instantiation process:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public TimeZoneInfo _timeZone;

  public MyClass(string timeZoneId)
  {
    _timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
  }
}

[TestMethod()]
public void MyClassCtorTest()
{
  TimeZoneInfo expected = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
  TimeZoneInfo actual = new MyClass("W. Europe Standard Time")._timeZone;

  Assert.IsTrue(expected.Equals(actual)); //This test passes!

  Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); //This test fails!
}
```

I found out that Assert.IsTrue(...) passes whereas Assert.AreEqual(...) fails:
"Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rom, Stockholm, Wien>. Actual:<(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rom, Stockholm, Wien>."

Since "Equals" is overridden in TimeZoneInfo class, I don't get what's going on, here. Could you help me to make pass the second assertion? Thank you very much in advance!

Rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your passing test calls

```
bool Equals(TimeZoneInfo)
```

Your failing test implicitly calls

```
bool Equals(object)
```

In the [.NET 4.0 version of `TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), `Equals(object)` has not been overridden; in [.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it has.

Comment: Hi Jon, I'm using .NET 4.0 as stated on top of my message. ;-)

Oh, damn it! You're totally right! I just discovered that in .net 4.5 "Equals" is overridden; however, in .net 4.0 it isn't! Wtf!!

Thx a lot!

Comment: @macrobbsen: Looking at the docs, it may be overridden in the *full* framework version of .NET 4.0, but not the client profile.

Comment: @macrobbsen: Oops, was reading the wrong docs - and the 4.5 docs are slightly misleading as the 4.5 documentation talks about the Equals(object) being inherited in the *client profile* but doesn't mention the non-client-profile.

Comment: @macrobbsen Also, if you use NUnit or XUnit tests, it would pass since they have type-safe assertions.